# How can I insert text from an external file onto a div?

Tags: file, html, text, external

As the title says; I want the content of an external file *(text,html,php etc.)* onto a div.
There is basically text in an external file, called: text_1.txt or *text_1.html* , and I want that text displayed within a div that is located on a homepage.

---

The perfect solution would be a pretty basic code to display text from a text or html file
by inserting it onto a div classed: *content*

Here I have illustrated the issue with basic code, use this as an example to write a solution.

Code in text_1.html:

```
<p>Hello world.</p>
```

Code in index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="content"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is as simple as I can put it.
I highly appreciate all the answers I receive, thank you.

PS here are some things you should avoid answering:

- Use iframes, or any other frame type solution.
- Make use of the onclick function within jquery etc.
- Use ineffective textfields to replace certain text.
- Make usage of an insertion code for virtual server or similar methods.

Comment: Any sane solution to this would simply use a server side solution - why isn't this an option?

Comment: Becasue I have to work with servers that do not support SSI.

Comment: In that case, I'd really recommend that you change to a different hosting provider - any solution implemented without a server side script of some kind will be horribly, horribly compromised. (e.g.: Injecting via JavaScript will mean that the content won't be indexed by search engines, etc.)

Comment: @Nikita, not SSI, but php/python/ruby or why do they unacceptable too?

Comment: I tried those, though apparently those languages don't like me and decide not to work, so I have to resort to lame iframes, which I highly discourage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just do it with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.content').load('text_1.html');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for some reason. It should be good with jquery 1.8.3, though I do not get visible text in the div.

Comment: Where is text_1.html in your solution?

Comment: text_1.html is in the same location as the document which includes the code above. So it should work if I am not mistaken.

Comment: does not work for me giving me this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:,. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this unless and until you use Server Side Includes using PHP, ASP, or JSP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

If you want to do it using php you can use this:

```
require_once('filename.php'); /* For including files */
```

Or use native functions to open `.txt` files in your pages

Comment: I can't seem to write proper code to make your php solution work, is there an alternative way or am I doing something wrong?